# How to send CString through sockets?

Tags: sockets, mfc, c-strings

I'm trying to program a chatting program.
I ask you guys for help since I have little problem.
when I try to send a `CString` formatted strings, it only receives first letter of the string.
I'm using `CAsyncSocket` for sockets.
I tried it with `char*` format string, it worked.
Can you guys tell me what is wrong?

My code is like below:

worked.

```
char* buf = new char[m_strMsg.GetLength()];
buf = "helloworld!";
m_ClientSocket.Send("sended", m_strMsg.GetLength());
m_ClientSocket.Send(buf, 10);
```

not worked.

```
CString a = _T("helloworld!");
m_ClientSocket.Send(a,10);
```

I've also tried:

```
CString a = _T("helloworld!");
char* buf = new char[a.GetLength()];
buf = (LPSTR)(LPCTSTR)a;
m_ClientSocket.Send(buf,a.GetLength()];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the proper UNICODE-compliant way of doing it:

```
CStringW sMessage = L"Hello World";
// convert from UTF-16 (UCS-2) to UTF-8
CStringA sMessageA = CW2A(sMessage, CP_UTF8);
const size_t nBytes = sizeof(CStringA::XCHAR) * sMessageA.GetLength();
CByteArray Message; 
Message.SetSize( nBytes );
std::memcpy( Message.GetData(), (const BYTE*)(LPCSTR)sMessageA, nBytes );
m_ClientSocket.Send(Message.GetData(), Message.GetSize());
```

Comment: Error: no suitable user-defined conversion from ATL::CW2A to CStringA exists
my environment is visual studio 2015.

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code snippet I've provided or did you modify it? Are you using Unicode Character Set in your project settings? The code compiles and works just fine in VS 2015.

Comment: First line should be `CStringW sMessage = L"Hello World";`. The calls to `GetBuffer`/`ReleaseBuffer` on *sMessageA* are not required, since you don't need **write** access. Casting to `BYTE*` (instead of `const BYTE*`) is the core of the issue.

Comment: Good catch. I've updated the code snippet to address your suggestions.